# Terminal vi mode: Scrolling through previous lines and outputs

Tags: vim, terminal, scroll, vi, xterm

I recently started using the terminal's (xterm) vi mode. I love not having to move my fingers from the keyboard, but then I want to copy part of the output from the previous line into my current line, and I switch to the mouse.

Is there a way to move my cursor through the terminal, then go into visual mode and select a few words, then copy it?

- I know k/j scroll from the history, but I want to move through the output of the previous lines.
- I know there are some escape sequences that work on some terminals, but I can't seem to get them to work on mine. And a pure vi-mode solution is best, obviously.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a great answer, but tmux can do this out of the box. [Here's a blog post](http://dudenbostel.leanside.com/2014/01/copy-paste-in-tmux/) on remapping the keys to match vi's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because nobody else did...

- It seems that there's no way to do this in a normal terminal. Escape sequences basically move the cursor around the terminal (so you can overwrite previous text), as described here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes. But there's no way of selecting text that's built into the terminal (except with the mouse). Even `vi-mode` needs to open a temporary file in `vi` to select text (this is what happens when you use `v` for visual mode).
- As Jordan pointed out, `tmux` can do this with an excellent "command mode". This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

On my xterm, I place the cursor in command mode on the word to start the copy. Use the 'y' key to yank plus the number of words, '5' with the 'w' key for words. Move the cursor where to put the words with the 'p' key. It is okay to use 'o' to open a new line, [ESC] key to go back to command mode before the 'p' put command.

```
Now is the time for all good people to
 come to the aid of their country.
```

Put the cursor on time, y5w, move cursor, p.

```
time for all good people
```